# How to extract part of object initializer?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, refactoring

### Problem

I have following repository, which queries db and constructs custom objects:

```
public class PatientCardRepository
{
    public PatientCardRepository(DbSet<PersonModel> people)
    {
        _people = people;
    }
    private DbSet<PersonModel> _people;

    public IEnumerable<PatientCardObject> GetPatientCardDataWithVisits(int personId)
    {
        return _people.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(person => person.Id == personId)
            .Select(person => new PatientCardObject
            {
                Person = new Person // COMMON PART
                {
                    FirstName = person.FirstName,
                    LastName = person.LastName,
                    Addresses = person.Addresses
                        .Where(address => address.IsCurrent && address.AddressTypeId == AddressType)
                        .Select(address => new Address
                        {
                            City = address.City,
                            Street = address.Street,
                            StreetNo = address.StreetNo,
                            ZipCode = address.ZipCode
                        }),
                },
                Visits = person.PatientVisits.Select(visit => new Visit
                {
                    Description = visit.Description,
                    StartTime = visit.StartTime,
                    EndTime = visit.EndTime,
                })
            }).Take(100);
    }

    public IEnumerable<PatientCardObject> GetPatientCardData(int personId)
    {
        return _people.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(person => person.Id == personId)
            .Select(person => new PatientCardObject
            {
                Person = new Person // COMMON PART
                {
                    FirstName = person.FirstName,
                    LastName = person.LastName,
                    Addresses = person.Addresses
                        .Where(address => address.IsCurrent && address.AddressTypeId == AddressType)
                        .Select(address => new Address
                        {
                            City = address.City,
                            Street = address.Street,
                            StreetNo = address.StreetNo,
                            ZipCode = address.ZipCode
                        }),
                }
            }).Take(100);
    }
}
```

I want to extract the COMMON PART (get rid of the copy-paste).

### Failed attempts

I have tried following solutions, but all failed:

**Changing Select clause to multi-line expression:**

```
public IQueryable<PatientCardObject> GetPatientCardDataWithVisits(int personId)
{
    return _people.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(person => person.Id == personId)
        .Select(person => 
            {
                var p = new PatientCardObject();
                p.Person = CreatePersonFromModel(person);
                return p;
            });
}
```

This fails because Select accepts only expression lambdas (multi-lines are not allowed)

**Using Inlcudes in the first place, then Select after materialization.**

```
public IEnumerable<PatientCardObject> GetPatientCardDataWithVisits(int personId)
{
    var filteredPeople = (IEnumerable)(_people.AsNoTracking()
        .Include(person => person.Address)
        .Include(person => person.PatientVisits)
        .Where(person => person.Id == personId));

    return filteredPeople
        .Select(person => 
            {
                var p = new PatientCardObject();
                p.Person = CreatePersonFromModel(person);
                return p;
            }).Take(100);
}
```

This fails, because it selects too many rows and columns. In this example *all* addresses for person are selected, not only current (filtering is done after materialization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we'll start out by having a method to get all of the information that you need by using the method that selects the most information.  From that, we'll modify it to return an `IQueryable` rather than an item, to allow for deferred execution:

```
private IQueryable<PatientCardObject> GetPatientCardDataWithVisitsHelper(int personId)
{
    return _people.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(person => person.Id == personId)
        .Select(person => new PatientCardObject
        {
            Person = new Person // COMMON PART
            {
                FirstName = person.FirstName,
                LastName = person.LastName,
                Addresses = person.Addresses
                    .Where(address => address.IsCurrent && address.AddressTypeId == AddressType)
                    .Select(address => new Address
                    {
                        City = address.City,
                        Street = address.Street,
                        StreetNo = address.StreetNo,
                        ZipCode = address.ZipCode
                    }),
            },
            Visits = person.PatientVisits.Select(visit => new Visit
            {
                Description = visit.Description,
                StartTime = visit.StartTime,
                EndTime = visit.EndTime,
            })
        });
}
```

(This is just `GetPatientCardDataWithVisits` without the call to `First` and a different name.)

Then we'll just have two calls to it, one that returns the first item, another than "removes" the unneeded information:

```
public PatientCardObject GetPatientCardDataWithVisits(int personId)
{
    return GetPatientCardDataWithVisitsHelper(personId).First();
}

public PatientCardObject GetPatientCardData(int personId)
{
    return GetPatientCardDataWithVisitsHelper(personId)
        .Select(person => new PatientCardObject
        {
            Person = person.Person,
            Visits = person.Visits.Where(v => false),
        }).First();
}
```

Comment: I modified the question to better reflect real situation. It now returns collection instead of single item, but I think your solution will work anyway. I'll try it in second

Comment: Sorry, LINQ doesn't support that :(
System.NotSupportedException : The type 'PatientCardObject' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.

Comment: @joozek Then just edit to ensure that no visits are selected in the second case.

Comment: LINQ generates about twice as big query, but doesn't touch unnecessary tables and runs in approx. same time, so I can say it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your second example has almost got it right. Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<PatientCardObject> GetPatientCardDataWithVisits(int personId)
{
    var filteredPeople = _people.AsNoTracking()
        .Include(person => person.Address)
        .Include(person => person.PatientVisits)
        .Where(person => person.Id == personId)
        .Take(100)
        .AsEnumerable()
       .Select(x => new PatientCardObject { Person = CreatePersonFromModel(x) });

    return filteredPeople;
}
```

This will only retrieve 100 from the DB.

Comment: Your solution is ok, but my question was not :) I modified it to better reflect real situation and now it returns collection instead of single item.

Comment: @joozek I've updated my solution. I think it'll work for you.

Comment: But that's exactly my second failed attempt. I don't see any difference :(

Comment: It's not the same, it's very different: in yours, you try to do the `Select` and `Take` on the `IQueryable`, which tells it to do that on the server, which it can't do. In mine, I `Take` and then do `AsEnumerable`, so it retrieves 100 `PersonModel` objects from the DB, and then `Select` to convert them to `PatientCardObject`s in the .Net code.

Comment: ok, but you select all the addresses, not only the current. You must realize, that the example I wrote is just a model of much more complicated situation I work with